# When push notification comes, if the user click the app icon instead of clicking the notification to open this app

Tags: iphone, push-notification

When push notification comes, it the user click the app icon instead of clicking the notification to open this app.
Then how can I get the notification payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can't.

You can only get the payload when launching from Notification Center because it means the user is interested in that specific notification. If you choose to ignore the notification and open the app by pushing the icon, you won't be able to get the push payload.

They have seemingly designed the architecture in such a way as to prevent the processing of piled up push payloads (say that 10 times).

This is proven because they really only allow you to process a push payload (when the app is closed or in the background) by going through individual notifications. If this wasn't the case, they would have to allow push payload processing code to run for all apps even when they were closed or in the background state.